# Junit 4, how to disable creating new instance of Test per test method

Tags: java, testing, junit4

Is there some way to disable creation new instance of Test per @Test ?

Comment: You can't, its just the way JUnit works.  If you have objects that can be created for all tests, label a static method @BeforeClass and set static variables in it

Comment: @Lucas and `@AfterClass` for cleanup

Comment: @user1013149, if that resolves your issue, mark the answer below.

Comment: @Lucas While this is true, you could argue that when using @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) with your tests, this no longer holds. That why for such a case a SingleInstanceRunner as posted in an answer seems to be the right choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of making this an answer:

```
public class MyTestClass {
    private static String onceForAllTests;

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        onceForAllTests = null; // silly, but just to demonstrate
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        onceForAllTests = "This is set once for all tests";
    }

    @Test
    public void sillyTest {
        String someTestValue = "This is set during method";
        assertNotEquals( onceForAllTests, someTestValue );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One instance per test is the way JUnit works by default. You can, however, write your own test runner which uses one single instance for all tests. You'll probably want to start by extending [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up arriving independently at the solution suggested above by Mathew.  I thought would post my short solution here.

The code in Kotlin:

```
class SingleInstanceRunner<T>(clazz : Class<T>) : BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(clazz) {
   val instance : Any by lazy { super.createTest() }

   override fun createTest() = instance
}
```

Here is the (untested) Java translation of the above:

```
public class SingleInstanceRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
   private Object instance;

   public SingleInstanceRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
       super(clazz);
   }

   @Override
   protected synchronized Object createTest() throws Exception {
       if (instance == null) {
           instance = super.createTest();
       }

       return instance;
   }
}
```

With this solution, annotate your test class with this runner.

In Kotlin:

```
@RunWith(SingleInstanceRunner::class)
class MyTest {
   ...
}
```

In Java:

```
@RunWith(SingleInstanceRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
   ...
}
```

This is used in combination with `@FixMethodOrder` to employ junit in some system test type scenarios.